# PHP preg_replace and read the attribute within the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The string I have used to looking for is below

```
<!-- PART -->
```

And it was easy, I just do

```
preg_replace('/<!-- PART -->/', $value);
```

But now I realise I need a new attribute to be added in the string (ID)

```
<!--  PART ID="zoneA" -->
```

So is it a way I can search for star with `<!-- PART` and end with `-->` and also if its possible to read the **ID** attribute value as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (preg_match_all('/<!--[\w\s]+ID="(\w+)"\s?-->/', $text, $matches)){
    echo $matches[1][0];//id
}
```

You can use the same pattern for preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/<!--[\w\s]+ID="(\w+)"\s?-->/', $value, $text);
```

Do both together:

```
$pattern = '/<!--[\w\s]+ID="(\w+)"\s?-->/';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches)){
    $id = $matches[1][0];
    preg_replace($pattern, $value, $text);
}
```

Comment: Wow legend it works and it did read the ID attribute, but preg_replace failed tho

Comment: can i do a whole string replace after i get the ID value? => <!--  PART ID="zoneA" --> would love to give u a tick still need 1 min :)

Comment: @bluebill1049 - I just updated with code to do both together.

Comment: actually one more small question, what if the string appear twice this pattern, can you read id one by one?  String => test<!--  PART ID="zoneA" --> test <!--  PART ID="zoneB" -->

Comment: @bluebill1049 - You can use `print_r($matches)` to see the structure of the array. In this case your ids should be `$matches[1][0]`, `$matches[1][1]`, `$matches[1][2]`, etc. The number `1` in the first key indicates that you want what is in the parenthesis of the pattern as opposed to `0` which matches the whole expression.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
if( preg_match_all("/<!--[\w\s]+ID="(\w+)"\s?-->/",$text,$err_program)) {
print_r($err_program);
preg_replace("/<!--[\w\s]+ID="(\w+)"\s?-->/",$value,$text)
}
```